# How would I go about creating a smooth interior to a helmet?

Tags: modeling, objects, vertices, workflow, sculpting

First of all, I am incredibly inexperienced at the blender. I made this helmet, and the exterior looks good. However, the underside is warped because of how I modeled it. It is supposed to be 3d printed, and the inside needs to be smooth to fit on someone's head. I currently have a solidify modifier on the model, and I tried applying it and pulling all of the interior vertices out of the spikes and into the helmet void. But it just causes a lot of creases and doesn't seem like best practice. How would I make the underside one smooth surface that matches the general shape of the helmet without the spikes?

[image: Current Underside of Helmet]
[image: Current Underside of Helmet]

Comment: the best idea would be to use some low poly head, cut the top of the head and join it to your helmet and connect those 2 parts with topology, this way you will get smooth inside (however you will have to not use solidify because that would make it messy